# Adding together the elements of list in nested dictionary - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, element

I have nested dictionaries, below are the outputs from code i have thus far which is exactly how i need and want them to be. I'm trying to add the list elements of the second dictionary-group of ID numbers; together to get the total occurrences that has happened for each element in relation to the first dictionary; which is a specific date

`{'2014-06-14': 
    {'205089113': [0, 1, 0, False, True], 
    '268243219': [0, 1, 0, False, True], 
    '216535211': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '207385741': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '207018490': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '204059430': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '209169283': [0, 1, 0, False, True], 
    '232067397': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '204718647': [0, 1, 0, False, True], 
    '205438195': [0, 1, 0, False, True]}, 
'2014-06-20': 
    {'209989276': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '209840693': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '207067397': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '207919002': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '204718498': [2, 1, 0, False, True], 
    '204437024': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
    '219878931': [1, 0, 0, False, True]},`

An example of what i mean is
`'2014-06-14':[0,5,0,0,10],'2014-06-20': [8,1,0,0,7]}`

Each time i try len() or even Counter module i get a key error

code below gives me the number of occurrences of the second dictionary but cannot seem to crack coding for adding together its list elements, not sure if there's a direct way that i am not understanding or if it's even possible

`for date in dates.keys():
    print date, len(dates[date].keys())`

Trying to be pointed in the right direction

Comment: You might want to tag your post with [`python`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), rather than with very unspecific tags like `nested`

Comment: Does your expected output have anything to do with the input dictionaries that you've posted?!?

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `{'2014-06-14':[0,5,0,0,10],'2014-06-20': [8,1,0,0,7]}`

Comment: Yes my expected output should be a reference of the dictionaries i posted. That's exactly what the output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your posted output is wrong and the expected output equals to `{'2014-06-14':[0,5,0,0,10],'2014-06-20': [8,1,0,0,7]}`. The following will fit your needs:

```
d = {'2014-06-14': {'205089113': [0, 1, 0, False, True],
                    '268243219': [0, 1, 0, False, True],
                    '216535211': [0, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '207385741': [0, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '207018490': [0, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '204059430': [0, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '209169283': [0, 1, 0, False, True],
                    '232067397': [0, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '204718647': [0, 1, 0, False, True],
                    '205438195': [0, 1, 0, False, True]},
     '2014-06-20': {'209989276': [1, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '209840693': [1, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '207067397': [1, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '207919002': [1, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '204718498': [2, 1, 0, False, True],
                    '204437024': [1, 0, 0, False, True],
                    '219878931': [1, 0, 0, False, True]}}

result = {}
for key in d:
    values = zip(*d[key].values())
    result[key] = [sum(value_tuple) for value_tuple in values]
print result
```

Comment: Thanks alot. is zip() a way to combine multiple arrays, and does it matter if those arrays aren't the same type, length, etc??

Comment: Zip returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each list. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you transform your sub-dictionaries into a Pandas dataframe, it will allow you do it easily :

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'2014-06-14': {'205089113': [0, 1, 0, False, True], 
                    '268243219': [0, 1, 0, False, True], 
                    '216535211': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '207385741': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '207018490': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '204059430': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '209169283': [0, 1, 0, False, True], 
                    '232067397': [0, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '204718647': [0, 1, 0, False, True], 
                    '205438195': [0, 1, 0, False, True]}, 
     '2014-06-20': {'209989276': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '209840693': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '207067397': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '207919002': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '204718498': [2, 1, 0, False, True], 
                    '204437024': [1, 0, 0, False, True], 
                    '219878931': [1, 0, 0, False, True]}}

new_d = {}
for k in d.iterkeys():
    new_d[k] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d[k], orient="index")
```

and then :

```
out = {}
for k in new_d:
    out[k] = new_d[k].sum().tolist()

print out
{'2014-06-14': [0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0], '2014-06-20': [8.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0]}
```

Having Pandas dataframes will allow you to apply easily other functions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll look more into Pandas, but i'm just starting to get familiar with python